# Can you download a AWS QuickSight dashboard to view offline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Can you download an AWS QuickSight dashboard as pdf or another file to view offline on desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can e-mail a snapshot of the dashboard on a scheduled basis, but there is no other general-purpose export / download / save to PDF functionality.

Perhaps printing to a PDF printer would be sufficient (e.g. "Microsoft Print to PDF", Pdf Creator, Foxit, Adobe PDF, etc).  Even printing to PDF can be problematic - both Microsoft Print to PDF and Adobe PDF leave out sections of the page when printing from FireFox. Printing from Chrome looks better than FireFox but still leaves out some of the visualizations.

The most effective option I have found is to use a screen capture tool that can handle scrolling (e.g. SnagIt's panoramic mode).